# On Ubuntu 12.04 is /etc/skel/ the correct place to put extra files for new users?

Tags: configuration, useradd, skel

On Ubuntu 12.04 is /etc/skel/ the correct place to put extra files for new users?

In the Linux Administration Handbook it mentions files from `/usr/local/lib/skel` which doesn't seem like an Ubuntu-esque path, nor does it exist on my fresh install of 12.04 server.

I'm just curious if there is anything like a `conf.d` directory for `/etc/skel/` or a `/usr/local/skel` and where that would be in the documentation.

I know you can specify which skeleton to use with the `SKEL` variable with adduser - just curious what the "correct" way to go about editing the skeletons is with this part of system administration is - if there is an agree'd upon one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything, files or directories, you put in `/etc/skel/` will be copied to a new users home directory.

You would put things there such as a custom .bashrc file. Alternately you would do a system configuration, sort of depends on what you are wanting to do exactly. For example, ssh settings would be in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (server) or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (client)